# Unwanted "data" wrapper in PHP response to AngularJS query

Tags: php, json, angularjs, http-headers

I am querying some server with AngularJS using `$http.get`

```
var onStuff = function(data) {
  console.log( "Stuff received: " + angular.toJson(data));
  $scope.stuff = data.data;
};

$http.get("https://some.server.net/stuff")
  .then(onStuff, onError);
```

My back end is written in php and returns a properly formatted JSON.
I checked that loading https://some.server.net/stuff in a browser and testing by command line "php stuff.php" . It looks something like (truncated with ... to fit this screen):

```
[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","name":"Name1"},
 {"id":"2","user_id":"1","name":"Name2"},
 ...
]
```

Please note this data is "unwrapped" or "just the array"
However, when `onStuff()` is invoked my array is "wrapped" inside another `data` object

Here is the console output

```
    Stuff received: 
    {"data":[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","name":"Name1"},
             {"id":"2","user_id":"1","name":"Name2"},...],
     "status":200,
     "config":{"method":"GET",
               "transformRequest":[null],
               "transformResponse":[null],
               "url":"https://some.server.net/stuff",
               "headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},
     "statusText":"OK"}
```

Here is the php stuff

```
<?
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

require_once("stuff.class.php");

$mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$list = Stuff::getList( $mysqli);
echo json_encode( $list);
$mysqli->close();
 ?>
```

I have been following a tutorial using github api, the JSON response was available directly in `data`
I am pretty sure this has to do with HTTP headers, but I hoped `content-type` would take care of it
**What should I do to remove the unwanted "data" wrapper?**

Comment: By down voting questions carefully crafted with genuine research effort behind it, you are turning SO into absolute crap. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you expect `onStuff` to receive only the deserialized JSON data, but that's not [what the API does](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#usage). The object passed to your `$http.get(...).then()` callback (i.e. `onStuff`) is a response object with five properties: `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config`, and `statusText`--which is exactly what you're seeing in your console output. The `data` property has the deserialized JSON data, which is why you have to do `$scope.stuff = data.data`.

If you want `onStuff` to receive only the deserialized JSON data, you'll have to call it through an intermediary:

```
$http.get("https://example.com/stuff")
  .then( function(response) {
           onStuff(response.data);
         } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the generic promise API (which seems to return an object with everything inside), use the `success` and `error` methods provided by `$http`:

```
var onStuff = function(data) {
  console.log( "Stuff received: " + angular.toJson(data));
  $scope.stuff = data.data;
};

$http.get("https://some.server.net/stuff")
  .success(onStuff).error(onError);
```

That should gives you the data in the format you expect. The full API is as follow:

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```